# What to do for using an EXTJS application work on mobile/tablets?

Tags: extjs

I have created an EXTJS application and want it to be work on mobile or tablet?
Is it possible to do that?if yes how can we do that?

When I was trying this on the iphone i was not able to see all the content/page at a time.
like i was not able to scroll or navigate through the page.

Can any one can help me out of this?????

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, but you wont like the way it is.

The best way to integrate a ExtJS browser application with some mobile devices is to develop an alternative for those, using [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/).

Comment: I know Sencha Touch is there for that but it is basically for mobile web app,but i need That Extjs 4.0 app to work on diffident devices.if there is  any way so that i can make EXTJS to work on both laptop & other device without using Touch.